# Dynamically redirect page based on URL?

Tags: url-rewriting, query, translation

I'm making a translation system for my website and I'm having troubles with URL rewriting. Each page is translated to multiple languages and should have different URLs for each language, e.g.:

```
/en/best-restaurants-in-tokyo

/it/migliori-ristoranti-a-tokyo

/fr/meilleurs-restaurants-à-tokyo
```

et cetera.

All those links should open the same post. All the translation related info (including the slug) is stored in a separate table. Changing the content of a post based on the selected language is trivial, but I can't come up with working URL rewriting.

Ideally, I would like to have code like that:

```
$languageShortNames = join('|', $languageShortNames);
add_rewrite_rule('('.$languageShortNames.')/(.*)/?', 'index.php?p=4015&language=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

but instead of `p` being a set number, it should be dynamically determined by some callback.

One working solution I've stumbled upon is to call `add_rewrite_rule` in a cycle for every existing post for each language. The problem is that my site has thousands of posts, so I think performance will be abysmal. It would really make more sense if I could simply chose the post ID I want to render in a callback by searching the translation table for a post ID with the slug.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you stick with [`add_rewrite_rule()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule), if language and title where set as meta data on the `/en/` post, then you can simplify the search down to a simple [`WP_Meta_Query()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query) for `/:lang/:title/` and pull the actually ID of the translated post there.

Translations for `/en/best-restaurants-in-tokyo`:

- `"/it/migliori-ristoranti-a-tokyo" => 4016`
- `"/fr/meilleurs-restaurants-à-tokyo" => 4017`

Comment: Unfortunately, all translation related stuff is stored in a separate table. It's a good solution, though, it will probably help someone in the future

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple ways you can do this. I'm going to suggest the following approach:

- Use *add_rewrite_tag* to identify the language
- Add a *pre_get_posts* action to pull the translation content based on the tag
- Using the *$wp_query* global variable, change the main post to the one you identified above

**The Code**

I haven't tested it, but the following code should approximate what you need to do:

```
// Create translation endpoint
// This changes the url, by adding a few variables
function translation_endpoint()
{
        // Add variables to populate from the url
        // match any two-digit lowercase letter combo
        add_rewrite_tag('%tr_language%', '([a-z]{2})' );
        // match any unicode alphanumeric. See: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php
        add_rewrite_tag('%tr_title%', '([\pL_-]+)' );

        // Add the rewrite rule. This sets the "tr_language" and "tr_title" variables 
        add_rewrite_rule('^([a-z]{2})/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?tr_language=$matches[1]&tr_title=$matches[2]', 'top');
}
// Hook into init, so we modify the url early on
add_action( 'init', 'translation_endpoint' );

// This checks if our variables are set, and changes our query appropriately
function translation_redirect()
{
        global $wp_query, $wpdb;

        // If not the main query, don't change anything.
        if ( !$wp_query->is_main_query() )
                return;

        // Get our variables
        $language = $wp_query->get('tr_language');
        $title = $wp_query->get('tr_title');

        // If tr_language is NOT set, then continue on without changing anything
        if (!$language)
                return;

        // Grab the post id
        // wpdb->prepare is important when working with untrusted data
        $select = $wpdb->prepare('SELECT post_id FROM my_custom_table WHERE language = %s AND title = %s LIMIT 1', $language, $title);
        // Grab just one result as an obj
        $result = $wpdb->get_row($select);

        // Can't find anything. So, return the default post.
        if (!$result)
                return;

        // Set the new post id
        $query->set('page_id',$result->post_id);
}
// Hook into pre_get_posts, so we modify the query before the post data is retrieved
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'translation_redirect' );
```

**REGEX**

One final note: Try to make your regex as specific as possible. Match from the beginning of the string with a carrot (^), and only match exactly what you're looking for. The (.*) in your code will match everything, including a slash. Your query may work for most cases, but it also matches these:

- example.com/my_new_plug**in/events/January/2017**

  -- (language => "in", title => "events/Jan..."
- example.com/archiv**es/123**

  -- (language => "es", title => "123")
- example.com/t**en/**

  -- (language => "en", title => "")

I gave a few examples of more specific queries above.

- **^** matches the beginning of the string
- **[\pL]** matches unicode alphanumerics (a-zA-Z) but not symbols.
- **[^/]** matches anything EXCEPT a slash
- **[a-z]{2}** matches exactly 2 lowercase letters
- **[a-z]+** matches ONE OR MORE letters, so is preferred to [a-z]*

Hopefully that'll help constructing something that works for you.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed response! Unfortunately, it's not working for me for some reason. I've made a separate question to discuss this particular problem: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/263606/60984
It would be great if you could take a look at it.

Comment: Hmm. I posted an answer over there as well. I tested this code, and was able to get a working solution locally. (I typoed on the $matches indexes, but otherwise it works fine). 

If the post isn't being changed, there are 3 possible reasons: 1) You aren't getting the right post, 2) you aren't modifying the global $wp_query variable, or 3) the $wp_query variable is being changed again later.

It's hard to tell you which one without being able to tinker with your site. My advice is to print out wp_query along the way (especially once in your template file) and see what's going on.