# Can not switch the queried post in pre_get_posts hook

Tags: wp-query, url-rewriting, query, get-posts, pre-get-posts

I need to dynamically change which page is being loaded based on the URL. It's a translation system, and a page's slug is different for each language. URLs look like that:

```
/en/best-restaurants-in-tokyo

/it/migliori-ristoranti-a-tokyo

/fr/meilleurs-restaurants-à-tokyo
```

The slugs are stored in a separate table, not in `wp_posts` or `wp_postmeta`. The only way I've found to accomplish this is by modifying global `WP_Query` object in `pre_get_posts` hook. The problem is that it doesn't work and I don't understand why. WordPress renders `index.php` instead of `single.php` as it should for all posts. If I open the page by the original slug or by ID (i.e. `?p=4033`), everything works fine.

Below is the code that demonstrates the problem.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'mt_handle_translation_redirect', 9999);
function mt_handle_translation_redirect ($query) {
    global $wpdb;

    if (!$query->is_main_query()) return;

    // "1178" is a valid post ID
    $query->set('page_id', 1178);
  }
```

If I open any post page (e.g. 'http://localhost/wordpress/?p=1010'), it will redirect to the page 1178 like expected. If I open a home page, it won't do any redirects.

If we add `add_rewrite_rule` to the code, it won't make redirects properly anymore, but instead it will try to render the home page:

```
add_action('init', 'mt_init');
function mt_init() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%tr_language%', '([a-z_-]+)' );
    add_rewrite_tag('%tr_title%', '([\pL_-]+)' );
    add_rewrite_rule('^(fr)/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?tr_language=$matches[1]&tr_title=$matches[2]', 'top');
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

It seems that when I call `index.php` without the specific post ID or a slug, it isn't possible to do a redirect to another page anymore, because it always renders a post list, like on a home page or a category page.

How do I make custom URLs to open another post?

Comment: You are writing the translation plugin?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I think by the time you get to pre_get_posts, the rule has been parsed and WordPress has already made some decisions about what the query is for. If a rewrite rule doesn't contain query vars that can generate a successful main query on its own, you need to hook query parsing and help things along.

Answer (score 1):

Huh. I double-checked. On my local server, this bit of code successfully changes the post:

```
function test_redirect()
{
        global $wp_query;
        $wp_query->set('page_id', 5); 
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'test_redirect');
```

You're going to have to do a bit of debugging. On a dev server, var_dump the $wp_query variable a few key places to check that it has what you expect it to.

One alternate solution is to hook into the [parse_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/parse_query) action to modify the query earlier.

Another option is hooking into [template_redirect](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) *later*, and then create a brand new wp_query object. This would generally be preferable if you were changing the post to something fundamentally different, instead of just another translation, because it will clear out any other variables that were set by parse_query earlier. It comes with the extra overhead of querying for the post twice. Here's the general idea:

```
function redirect_translation()
{
        global $wp_query;
        // Replace wp_query here... query_posts() should work too.
        $wp_query = new WP_Query(array('post_id' => 5));
}
add_action('template_redirect','redirect_translation');
```

Doing this in pre_get_posts will cause an infinite loop.

**EDIT:** Looking over your code again, how is *mt_handle_translation_redirect* being called? I suspect you may not be updating the global $wp_query object, which is why the real query isn't being modified. Verifying the contents of wp_query a few places (like your template file) would be a good start.

Comment: None of those seem to work in my case :( The weird thing is that it's getting the correct post, but it renders it on `index.php` rather than `single.php`. Here are both of query objects that are displayed during theme header rendering: https://www.diffchecker.com/RkHbYAAn (on the left is the query with the original slug that works fine, on the right is the same post retrieved with my URL rewriting rules).

Comment: Also, `mt_handle_translation_redirect` is called on action hook `pre_get_posts`, you can see it in `mt_translations_init` function in code above

Comment: The redirect itself seems to be working fine, the problem is that when I don't pass an exact post ID or slug to `index.php`, it starts to render it as a home page, instead of a single post page. If I make a redirect via `pre_get_posts`, everything works fine, but when I add `add_rewrite_rule` to make my custom URLs work with it, my problems appears. I'll update code in my initial post to demonstrate it better

Comment: Your rewrite rules contain no query vars that tell WordPress you are trying to load a single post. When that rule is parsed, the only type of query that has no native query vars set is the main blog query, that's why you see index.php. You either need to hook parse_query and do it yourself, or alter your rule to contain whatever native query var you need to have it parse successfully.

Comment: @Milo Thanks for the reply! Any idea on how to do it by hooking `parse_query`? I've tried a lot of ways of changing query in there, but none of them worked.

Comment: @VictorMarchuk - [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/177015/4771) has an example of manipulating the request before the `is_` conditionals are set. You can also just try setting the correct query vars for a single post query but give it dummy values, so it's identified as a single post query, then you can manipulate that value in a `pre_get_post` action. Not sure if that'll work, never tried it.

Comment: @Milo Wow, hooking to `request` actually did the trick! Thanks a lot! If you could post it as an answer, I will mark it as solved.

Comment: @VictorMarchuk - you can add your final code as an answer and accept it, it may be helpful to others in the future.